# ¿Como configurar variable de entorno en heroku?

Tags: bash, heroku

Me encontre en la necesidad de configurar unas variables de entorno en heroku para el despliegue en modo produccion de mi proyecto.

Las variable fueron las credenciales para el acceso de la base de dato

```
const DB_HOST    = process.env.DB_HOST    || 'localhost';
const DB_NAME    = process.env.DB_NAME    || 'nombre_base_dato';
const DB_USER    = process.env.DB_USER    || 'postgres';
const DB_PASS    = process.env.DB_PASS    || 'postgres';
const DB_CHARSET = process.env.DB_CHARSET || 'utf-8';
const DB_CLIENT  = process.env.DB_CLIENT  || 'postgresql';

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: {
        host:     "localhost",
        user:     "postgres",
        password: "postgres",
        database: "abeedb",
        charset:  "utf-8"
    }
},

production: {
    client: DB_CLIENT,
      connection: {
        host:     DB_HOST,
        user:     DB_USER,
        password: DB_PASS,
        database: DB_NAME,
        charset:  DB_CHARSET
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Heroku te permite desde la terminal de linux ejecutar mas funcionalidades puedes visualizarla te invito a ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
heroku help
```

obteniendo como resultado esto:

```
 access          manage user access to apps
 addons          manage add-ons
 apps            manage apps
 authorizations  OAuth authorizations
 buildpacks      manage the buildpacks for an app
 certs           a topic for the ssl plugin
 ci              run an application test suite on Heroku
 clients         OAuth clients on the platform
 config          manage app config vars
 domains         manage the domains for an app
 drains          list all log drains
 features        manage optional features
 git             manage local git repository for app
 keys            manage ssh keys
 labs            experimental features
 local           run heroku app locally
 logs            display recent log output
 maintenance     manage maintenance mode for an app
 members         manage organization members
 notifications   display notifications
 orgs            manage organizations
 pg              manage postgresql databases
 pipelines       manage collections of apps in pipelines
 plugins         manage plugins
 ps              manage dynos (dynos, workers)
 redis           manage heroku redis instances
 regions         list available regions
 releases        manage app releases
 run             run a one-off process inside a Heroku dyno
 sessions        OAuth sessions
 spaces          manage heroku private spaces
 status          status of the Heroku platform
 teams           manage teams
```

Para configurar las variable de entorno de nuestro proyecto en heroku, sigue los sigientes pasos:

1. Inicia tu logeo de tu cuenta y ingresa tus credenciales con

   - `heroku login`
2. Te ubicas sobre tu proyecto o te clonas si no lo tienes

   - `cd <Tu Proyecto>` ó `heroku git clone https://git.heroku.com/<Tu Proyecto>.git && cd <Tu Proyecto>`
3. ya listo para la configuracion de las variables de entorno

   - `heroku config:set DB_HOST='escribe-tu-host' 
     heroku config:set DB_USER='escribe-tu-user' 
     heroku config:set DB_PASS='escribe-tu-pass' 
     heroku config:set DB_NAME='escribe-tu-name' 
     heroku config:set DB_CHARSET='escribe-tu-charset'`
4. para ver los valores asignado a las variable solo con

   - `heroku config:get DB_HOST`
5. Adicional a esto si quieres ver todas las variables que tienes configuradas lo puedes ver con

   - `heroku run printenv`

con `heroku run` tu puedes ejecutar cualquier comando en el alojamiento de heroku y capturando la salida en tu terminal muy util para cualquier necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente le tienes que especificar para qué app es son las variables de entorno. Si no haces eso da el siguiente error:

```
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›    -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

Para que esto no pase de debemos de pasar el nombre que le dimos a nuestra aplicación dentro de la página de Heroku, algo tal que así:

`heroku config:set DB_HOST='escribe-tu-host' --app nombre-de-nuestra-app`

Aquí la referencia: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands