# Problemas archivo .ENV con TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment

soy nuevo con TypeScript.

Tengo esta estructura en mi proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer un `node dist/server.js` o `nodemon dist/server.js` no detecta las variables creadas en .ENV, sin embargo, si muevo el .ENV a la carpeta dist si que lo detecta. He probado tambien a cambiar la configuración de dotenv y parece que así si me funciona pero **no sé si es una buena práctica.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual sería la mejor solución?

Comment: https://blog.morizyun.com/javascript/library-typescript-dotenv-environment-variable.html

Answer (score 0):

Para credenciales que puedas manejar en el .env para nada es buena practica .  tendrias que trabajar con variables de entorno en donde lo quieras subir, como por ejemplo lo tiene heroku .
aca hay una seccion donde se toca ese tema
[¿Como configurar variable de entorno en heroku?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200261/como-configurar-variable-de-entorno-en-heroku)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la configuración con que llames al método `config` de dotenv, en particular la opción `path`, hay tres caminos:

1. No le pasas `path`: Asume por defecto que el `.env` está en el directorio desde donde ejecutas la aplicación `process.cwd()`. ([como se ve en el código](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/0e004970f08da84c6e381d7715182da2b23af311/lib/main.js#L56)).  Esa ruta es **absoluta**.
2. Le pasas `path` y éste empieza con  `~` ej, `dotenv.config({path:'~/proyecto/.env'})`, reemplaza la ~ con la **ruta absoluta** a tu home
3. Le pasas `path` y éste no empieza con `~`: conserva el argumento sin normalización.

En los tres escenarios, [luego procede a leer el `.env`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/0e004970f08da84c6e381d7715182da2b23af311/lib/main.js#L72):

```
const parsed = DotenvModule.parse(fs.readFileSync(dotenvPath, { encoding }))
```

En otras palabras, en la opción 3 es tu responsabilidad normalizar la ruta.

---

Si la raíz de tu proyecto está en `/var/www/proyecto`, y ejecutas `node dist/index.js` distintas normalizaciones te darán distinto resultado:

```
fs.readFileSync(`./.env`)   -> `/var/www/proyecto/.env`

fs.readFileSync(require.resolve(`./.env`))   -> `/var/www/proyecto/dist/.env`

fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(`./.env`))   -> `/var/www/proyecto/.env`

fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/.env`))   -> `/var/www/proyecto/dist/.env`
```

A simple vista, qué crees que pasaría si en producción la aplicación se corriera con `npm start`, y éste dijera

```
 cd dist && node index.js
```

¿Cambiaría la resolución relativa? ¿O será que la aplicación deploya solamente el subdirectorio `dist` y ese se convierte en la nueva raíz? Es un dato que no expones en tu pregunta pero yo tampoco estoy seguro de las potenciales inconsistencias. Optaría por quitar un grado de libertad pasando un path absoluto (y escribiéndolo en la consola) antes de seguir.

---

Con respecto a si es buena o mala práctica, en realidad mala práctica sería tener el `.env` bajo control de versiones, o tenerlo visible por browser. De ahí para adelante hay prácticas más eficientes que otras y ninguna es 100% segura. Usar un `.env` cuando la máquina corre más de un proceso productivo al menos te ayuda a no propagar accidentalmente el environment entre éstos.